# How to store Python functions in a SQLite table?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am creating a simple network monitoring web application in Python.

Given:

- I want to manage everything from the GUI. No requirement post-install to touch files on the host server.
- I want to be able to define custom checks in Python, and store those functions/checks in a SQLite database.

Questions:

- How should I store that textarea (python function) in the SQLite database?
- How do I call that function from another python script after I've pulled it out of the SQLite database?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project. Out of interest what is the motivation behind storing the python functions in a Database rather than in modules on the filesystem?

Comment: I think you'd want to use a lookup table instead of this convoluted way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite TEXT field is fine for that. And you can call function from the code like this:

```
>>> code = """
... def hello():
...     print 'Hello world'
... """
>>> exec code
>>> hello()
Hello world
```

But I suggest you to save the code on disk with random filename. Then filename can be saved in database and code can be used like a normal module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pickle - Python Object Serialization to convert your function to text and store this text in  the database. See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html